# Menu should not move when mouse over. Position should be fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a **responsive menu**. `font-weight` is set to normal. But on mouse hover, I'm changing the `font-weight` to **bold / italic**. Thats why the menu size is changing.

How can I prevent this?

```
div.menu a span {        
    color: #000000;    
    display: block;    
    font-size: 14px;    
    padding:5px 0;  
}
```

On mouse hover :

```
div.menu a span:hover {    
    color: #FFF; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/rfQC6/)

Comment: set the default width for menu in css width:40px; something like this

Answer (score 0):

In your **`div.menu a span:hover { }`** remove the **`font-size: 14px`** property and  **`div.menu a span{ }`** add **`line-height`** css property to solve this problem.

```
div.menu a span {        
    color: #000000;    
    display: block;    
    font-size: 14px;    
    padding:5px 0;  
    line-hegiht: 20px; /* set your self */
}

div.menu a span:hover {    
    color: #FFF; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not specify font-size in :hover mode as it will inherit from the `div.menu a span` .

Next if you could add line-height attribute to the `div.menu a span {` block, the issue of resizing can be resolved.

```
div.menu a span {        
    color: #000000;    
    display: block;    
    font-size: 14px;    
    padding:20px;  
    float: left;
    width: auto; // you can have fixed width also
}

div.menu a span:hover {    
    color: #FFF; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

Working demo : [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/YyRu7/2/)

Comment: @mohanedrias: My menu is horizontal not vertical.

Comment: Please mention width in the div.menu a span { working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/YyRu7/2/

Comment: @mohanmedrias: your code is correct but not working in my CSS...the width keep changing.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/rfQC6/2/ You need to specify fixed width for the items. Only then the width will not change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52261/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-poles)